# Libgdx rotating ellipse for collision detection

Tags: libgdx, ellipse

I try to use 2 ellipses to detect a collision if they overlap. I have to rotate the ellipses but I can't figure out how this works. I'm working with the "com.badlogic.gdx.math.Ellipse" class but it seems to have no method for rotating. Any ideas? Thx in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, LibGDX doesn't have in-built rotating functions for ellipses.

Instead, I'd either be resorting to a circle in which rotation does not matter, or use polygons to check intersection.

[Polygons](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Polygon.html) are formed through an array of float values (vertices), where, every even element of the array is the horizontal component (x) and the odd, the vertical component (y).

```
Polygon polygon1 = new Polygon(vertexSet1);
Polygon polygon2 = new Polygon(vertexSet2);
```

Then, by using an [Intersector](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html#overlapConvexPolygons-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Polygon-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Polygon-), you can then check whether these polygons have intersected. The more vertices, the more accurate your shape will be. Just remember to have 6 or more elements in your vertex array, as the 6 floats will give 3 (x, y) points which is the minimum required for a polygon.

```
if (intersector.overlapConvexPolygons(polygon1, polygon2) {
    //do your intersection code
}
```

The polygons themselves have commands to translate, scale and rotate, allowing for the rotations you mentioned above.